# jqgrid multiselect vs row selection

Tags: jqgrid

In my jqgrid I am expanding a subgrid on click on the row. But multi-select functionality also running on my grid. Whenever I click on any checkbox the grid also expand and collapse but I want to expand/collapse subgrid on the click on a row only.
Is there any way by which I can differentiate between the click on the row and a click on the CheckBox.

I am currently stopping the subgrid on click on checkbox very first time but not able to stop it from the second click because it makes the showSubGrid function unreachable.

```
$("#grid tr").on("click", function(event){
    selectedRowId =  $(this).attr("id");
    if($("#jqg_grid_"+selectedRowId).is(":checked"))
        $("#grid").jqGrid("collapseSubGridRow", selectedRowId);
    else
        showSubGrid(selectedRowId, event);
});
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used  - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= 4.7?

Comment: Thanks @TonyTomov for the concern but i handled the event before calling the function instead of checking for the checkbox.

Just like this:

if(event.target.type != "checkbox")
    showSubGrid(selectedRowId, event);

FYI i am using jqGrid 4.6